# ActiveRecord condition with count less than for association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `User` that `has_many` `messages`.
I need a create a query that will

`'Get me all users who's (message.opened == false) count < 3'`

Right now, I am using `User.all`, iterating through all users, and counting manually. I understand that this isn't very efficient and it can be all done in one query, but I am new to SQL/ActiveRecord so need some help here.
Thanks

Comment: does count is attribute in your model? i didn't understand what you actually need? all users whose message.opened == false ? What is the purpose of count here ? will you please explain the query you needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User.includes(:messages).group('users.id').having('SUM(IFNULL(messages.opened = 0, 1)) < 3')
```

It works at least on MySQL, **AND** assuming your boolean true are 1 in database.

**EDIT** I had reversed the condition

**PS** `IFNULL` is there to handle if `messages.opened` can be `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Rails 3 syntax. You can do something like:

```
User.joins(:messages).where(:messages => {:opened => false}).group(:user_id).having("COUNT(messages.id) < 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
User.includes(:messages).group("users.id").where("messages.opened = 0").having("count(messages.id) < 3")
```

This will create two queries, one for the grouped query, and one for eager loading the resulting users and messages with a join.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to your problem

```
User.includes(:messages).group("users.id").where("messages.opened = 0").having("count(messages.id) < 3")
```

but what else you can do is to create a scope for this

```
scope :not_opened_less_three_count, includes(:messages).group("users.id").where("messages.opened = 0").having("count(messages.id) < 3")
```

And then you can use it anywhere you needed as follow

```
User.not_opened_less_three_count
```

Comment: Not sure when it changed but by Rails 5 (maybe Rails 4.x) you should use ```eager_load``` in place of ```includes```.